# SQL how to count free reservations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables
Reservations

- `reservation no | trip ID |person ID| Status`
- `1              | 2       | 1       |  C` '
- `2              | 3       | 2       |  P` '
- `3              | 4       | 3       |  P` '
- `4              | 1       | 4       |  C` '
- `5              | 1       | 6       |  P` '
- `6              | 1       | 7       |  P` '
- `7              | 2       | 5       |  P` '

Where P stands for payed and C for Cancelled

And trips

- `trip ID        |trip Name|Date      | Free Places`
- `1              | Paris   |2016-12-18|  5` '
- `2              | New York|2016-12-17|  6` '
- `3              | Warsaw  |2016-12-15|  5` '
- `4              | London  |2016-12-20|  10` '

I want to select number of left free places  for each trip

- `trip ID        |trip Name|Date        | Free Places  | Left free Spaces`
- `1              | Paris   |2016-12-18  |  5           |      3`
- `2              | New York| 2016-12-17 |  6           |      5`
- `3              | Warsaw  |2016-12-15  |  5           |      4`
- `4              | London  |2016-12-20  |  10          |      9`

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Where do you find the dates you want to select?

Comment: ms sql, I want to get the last table

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried? What exact problem do you have? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a subquery of the reservation table which computes the number of spaces already taken for each trip.  Then join this back to the `trips` table to compute the number of spaces remaining.

```
SELECT t1.tripID,
       t1.tripName,
       t1.Date,
       t1.FreePlaces,
       t1.FreePlaces - COALESCE(t2.numBooked, 0) AS left_free_spaces
FROM trips t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT tripID, SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numBooked
    FROM Reservations
    GROUP BY tripID
) t2
    ON t1.tripID = t2.tripID
```

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen thank you for your help it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it may help you

```
create table #RESERVATION (revservation_no bigint,trip_ID bigint,person_id bigint,status char(5))

insert into #RESERVATION values(1,2,1,'C'),(2,3,2,'P'),(3,4,3,'P'),(4,1,4,'C'),(5,1,6,'P'),(6,1,7,'P'),(7,2,5,'P')

CREATE TABLE #TRIP (TRIP_ID BIGINT,TRIP_NAME VARCHAR(50),DATE_ DATE ,FREE_PLACES BIGINT)

INSERT INTO #TRIP VALUES (1,'PARIS','2016-12-18',5),(2,'NEW YORK','2016-12-17',6),(3,'WARSAW','2016-12-15',5),(4,'LONDON','2016-12-20',10)

;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT DISTINCT T.TRIP_ID,T.TRIP_NAME,T.DATE_,T.FREE_PLACES,COUNT(revservation_no)AS LEFT_SPACES FROM #TRIP T
INNER JOIN #RESERVATION R ON R.trip_ID=T.TRIP_ID
WHERE status='P'
GROUP BY T.TRIP_ID,T.TRIP_NAME,T.DATE_,T.FREE_PLACES
)
SELECT TRIP_ID,TRIP_NAME,DATE_,FREE_PLACES,FREE_PLACES-LEFT_SPACES AS LEFT_FREE_PLACES  FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select      D1.trip_ID ,trip_Name, [Date] , D1.Free_Places,
            D1.Free_Places - Sum(Case
                                    When D2.Status = 'P' then 1 
                                    Else 0
                                End) as Left_free_Spaces
From        Trips D1
Inner Join  Reservations D2
    On      D1.trip_ID = D2.trip_ID
Group by    D1.trip_ID ,trip_Name, [Date] , Free_Places
```